# Remove first word from string if length is 1

Tags: python, string, strip

I want to remove the first character in a string, and the white space after it, only if the first word is one character.

Like this:

```
input = "A fish"
output = "fish"
```

Is there a way to do this without turning it into a list first?

Comment: Yes, e.g. using regex or just indexing into the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with indexing:

```py
def remove_first(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return s
    # if string is letter then a space then trim the first 2 chars
    if s[0].isalpha() and s[1].isspace():
        return s[2:]
    return s

remove_first("A fish") # "fish"
remove_first("fish") # "fish"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how:

```
text = "A fish"

if text[1] == ' ':
    text = text[2:]

print(text)
```

Output:

```
fish
```